# Overlay LaserScan data on Camera in rviz

Tags: rviz, laser, camera, hokuyo, overlay

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a setup with a simple VGA Camera and a Hokuyo 2D Laser and I want to OVERLAY the readings from the Hokuyo on the window of the camera in rviz. I can see the hokuyo readings on the main window and I can also see the camera image in a separate window. I've already set the frame_id for camera to /camera and for the hokuyo to /laser. Also I publish the tf for /world frame to each of the aforementioned frames. The camera is next to the laser so the translation transform for the camera is 0,0,0 and for the laser is like 0, 0.05 ,0 which means 5 cm at the right. I want to see a line on the camera window much as like in the rviz tutorials (second video around 2:40).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32508/overlay-laserscan-data-on-camera-in-rviz/) by [kabamaru](https://answers.ros.org/users/2240/kabamaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-24**:
Do you directly or indirectly publish transforms from  /world -> /camera and from /world -> /laser?

**Comment by [kabamaru](https://answers.ros.org/users/2240/kabamaru/) on 2012-04-24**:
i've tried
[ /world -> /camera , /camera -> /laser] & [ /world -> /camera , /world -> /laser]
is this what you mean? in the second case they are both direct children of the /world frame.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-25**:
Did you try moving the camera window on top of the laser display area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

well it was a matter of some transform manipulation after all. the POVs of the camera and the laser (hokuyo) are not aligned. just for reference the tf that worked for me was: xyz ypr [0 0 0 -1.57 0 -1.57]

---

Originally posted by [kabamaru](https://answers.ros.org/users/2240/kabamaru/) with karma: 35 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0